# How to remove extra account from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, office365

Every time I do anything with O365 it pops a box making me select which account I want, listing both my real account and also a domain service account.

In the "Email & accounts" panel, I have both my normal work account as well as the extra service account (listed as "work or school").  Per MS documentation I should be able to click on it and then select "remove".  However, the "remove" button does not exist for it.  I only have a "manage" button.

I've tried logging into it on O365 (as I do know the password to it) and signing out of it, but it still remains stuck on my system.

Comment: Do you have local admin rights?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I do have local admin rights

Comment: This is still driving me crazy as since it has 2 accounts now it will routinely interrupt what I'm doing to ask me which one to use.  It has happened several times right in the middle of file transfers, which causes them to abort.  When moving large nested directories that is a whole big ball of sadness...  Getting REAL close to reformatting my computer!